# How to change keyboard movement to zqsd controls in A-frame scene?

Tags: keyboard, aframe

By adding the `wasd-controls`-attribute, you can move using this keys on a Qwerty keyboard. But I have an Azerty keyboard. My question is now could I use this keys: <kbd>Z</kbd> *(up)*, <kbd>Q</kbd> *(left)*, <kbd>S</kbd> *(down)* and <kbd>D</kbd> *(right)* or maby the arrow keys <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `WASD-CONTROLS` enable You to move using the arrow keys.
2. I looked Through `WASD-CONTROLS` in [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe-v0.5.0.js), and it seems You can't add any attribute to the `WASD-CONTROLS` to make them work with other keys.
    If You want to make it work on zqsd, You need to copy the code of the `WASD-CONTROLS` and rewrite the listeners, or make an easy component with Your own implementation of acceleration etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've found that ZQSD also works with `wasd-controls` component. Forgotten to answer my question.